# Maven points to incorrect java folder when I upgrade solr 4.4 in pom.xml

Tags: maven, solr, solrj

I am currently using solr 4.3.1. I need to upgrade it to solr 4.4. When I change the maven pom to 4.4.0 for solr-core, I am getting error like  **The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'javadir\Java\lib\tools.jar** where as my java path is **javadir/Java/jdkversion/lib/tools.jar**. Whereas my pom.xml is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using eclipse.How to fix this issue?Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. In my machine java was pointing to some other JRE. I uninstalled that JRE. now it is working fine.

Comment: good to hear that its solved :). Can you please mark it as resolved/answered for the reference of other visitors. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when we import any maven project into Eclipse, Eclipse makes some files on filesystem - .project, .classpath, a folder .settings,. It seems that Eclipse doesn't update these correctly.

Delete these and import them again.

Or alternatively you  can check here .

```
     Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs
```

and see is it pointing to default JRE , if yes then change to to your JDK , something like this

```
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.X.X.X
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope it is pointing the jdk location. but still getting this error.